# Array of different classes

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I recently started learning object-oriented programming and now i have some difficulties. All i have to do is to put in an array different classes that inherit the same base, and then show on the screen all members of the array with their specific characteristics. My array should look like:

```
[first person1("John",true)] [second person2("Michael",false)] [first person3("Tanya",false)], ...;
```

Then i want to show all members of the array using method getInfo(), something like:

```
for(int i=0;i < numberOfElements;i++) array[i].getInfo();  
// where numberOfElements will be incremented in the constructor
```

How could i do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class base
{
    protected: string name;
    public: virtual string getName()=0;
};

class first:public base
{
    protected: bool Medic;
    public: first(string Name="",bool check=false) {name=Name; Medic=check;};
    public: virtual string getName() {return name;};
    public: bool isMedic() {return Medic;};
    public: void getInfo() 
    {
        cout << endl << name; 
        if(Medic) cout << " is medic.";
        else cout << " is not a medic.";
    };

};

class second:public base
{
    protected: bool Janitor;
    public: second(string Name="",bool check=false) {name=Name; Janitor=check;};
    public: virtual string getName() {return name;};
    public: bool isMedic() {return Janitor;};
    public: void getInfo() 
    {
        cout << endl << name; 
        if(Medic) cout << " is a janitor.";
        else cout << " is not a janitor.";
    };
};

int main()
{
    base* a[100];
    // Code
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rather use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<base>> a;`.

Comment: I don't know how could i add to the array different classes and then, when i want to show their info, how could i know if they are first class or second class;

Comment: You can't put different types in one array, but you can make an array of pointers to base type, i.e. `unique_ptr<base>`, then you can your function on each element. But you'll need to declare `getInfo()` inside bace class too.

Comment: @braga _" how could i know if they are first class or second class;"_ You don't need to. That's what (virtual) polymorphism is for.

Comment: So i would simply do something like array[5] = new first("John",true); ?

Comment: Why at SO everyone recommends new and modern programming elements to newcomer? Come on, no one of you recommending `vector`, `unique_ptr` did know about it when you started learning C++. Give new guys a break!

Comment: Neither existed when I started programming in C++. Probably one of the reasons I'm so screwed up today.

Comment: @Ajay because it's far, far easier to learn modern c++ than c with classes, or at least it's far less effort to get it right...

Comment: @jaggedSpire, that's not true. If you want to learn classes, grab a Java or C# book. C++ guys need to know the details. You cant throw them a vector or a unqiue_ptr. It doesn't work that way. Now or then, they will hit the wall for not knowing behind-the-scene details, program will crash, and they will curse C++

Comment: @user4581301, Oh so you admit that you might have learnt it well by obscure syntax of `std::unique_ptr<base[]>`, and would have fixed complex error thrown by compiler? I strongly doubt that. None of data-structure book will teach pointers, DS elements etc. that way.

Comment: @Ajay please do give an example where a newbie might crash and burn for not knowing the details behind vector and unique_ptr, because I really can't think of one where they wouldn't also crash and burn given a c-style array. C++ is a language where you can control how low-level your program is, and choose to double down to the metal only when and where you *need* to do so. While low-level details are exceedingly useful, and while the ability to make use of them *is* one of the benefits of the language, newbies always, always make the mistake of too little abstraction rather than too much.

Comment: The low-level details of c++ should be taught *after* a basic understanding of the general *interface* is provided. Say you're trying to teach how passing variables into functions works. Would a vector or a c-style array present a less confusing face to a newbie when passed by value into a function? A *vector*, because altering it won't alter the vector passed as an argument. This whole argument is based off of the idea that people by and large need to know little details of c++, but that's not really true. C++ has *1300* pages of details in its specification.

Comment: @jaggedSpire, a `unique_ptr` holding a pointer to an stack allocated object. ` int n;
 auto ptr = &n;
 unique_ptr<int> up(ptr);`

Comment: Most of these details are little bits and pieces created with the Principle Of Least Surprise, *specifically so* newbies don't get surprised and have to delve into details, more than they absolutely have to.

Comment: @jaggedSpire, Don't need much of text. I gave very simple example for how a newbie can enter into trouble land.

Comment: @Ajay As long as the newbie has some understanding of pointers or references I don't see how that could be a problem. Altering the contents alters the contents. Altering the target alters the target.

Comment: @jaggedSpire, Exactly! That's my point buddy - the person needs to know the BASICS. You cannot throw `vector` without telling them what a stack memory and what a heap memory is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `new` with appropriate class type, like this:

```
int main()
{
    base* a[100];
    a[0] = new first("Janit", false);
    a[1] = new second("Romeo", true);
    return 0;
}
```

But, while printing it's up to you on how to determine what `a[i]` type is! Later you can free the memory by just calling `delete` for each element:

```
delete a[i];
```

It is NOT equivalent to any of these:

```
delete []a;
delete a;
delete []a[i];
```

Note that this is just starting point for you to proceed, and not a complete solution.

Comment: @user4581301, Doesn't matter at this stage. Let the guy learn something. I would have advised him to allocate memory for pointer using `new` instead of having array of size `100`. Or may be `make_unique<base[]>`. I tried to keep things simple. Why at SO, everyone wants to show off their mastery?

Comment: Take a read here to learn about how new and delete works. new without delete will leak memory.

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/69-dynamic-memory-allocation-with-new-and-delete/